# Android device doesn't capture video in low quality on Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Tags: android, video-capture

It seems that even after I am setting the video recorder profile to low, the video is in the highest quality.

Here is my code :

```
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.unlock();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

 //when removing these comments I get an exception on my 4.2.2 device when calling start() on the recorder.
/*      recorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
        recorder.setVideoSize(480, 360);

*/      
        recorder.setOrientationHint(90);
        file = FileUtils.getFileName(FileTypes.VIDEO);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        recorder.setOutputFile(FileUtils.getFileName(FileTypes.VIDEO).toString());
        recorder.setMaxDuration(45000);
```

Comment: I have the same code, and it is working fine.

Comment: @Lucifer What android version are you using? Is it the latest 4.2.2?

Comment: Android 2.3.3 to 4.0.4

Comment: @Lucifer apparently it doesn't work on my 4.2.2 version only.

Comment: ok, This may be problem in Jelly Bean, i havent test it in 4.1 or above

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Although this seems like the same as your code, It works for me.create a seperate instance for CamcorderProfile and set the recorder profile to this instance.

```
  CamcorderProfile cprofileLow = CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    recorder.setProfile(cprofileLow);
    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");
    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(3000000); // Approximately 3 megabytes
```

Please do notice that you have a high end device(since yours is of 4.2.2), you may get a comparitively good resolution provided,it is the lowest possible resolution in your device.